# How to fix Postcss & glob-parent npm install error?

Tags: node.js, postcss

**when entering npm fund I get errors**

**this is not my project, so I don't really understand how to fix it, my nodejs version 21.1**

```
glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
glob-parent before 5.1.2 vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service in enclosure regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar
    watchpack-chokidar2  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2
      watchpack  1.7.2 - 1.7.5
      Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack-chokidar2
      node_modules/watchpack

postcss  <8.4.31
Severity: moderate
PostCSS line return parsing error - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7fh5-64p2-3v2j
No fix available
node_modules/css-mqpacker/node_modules/postcss
  css-mqpacker  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-mqpacker
```

npm audit fix & npm audit fix -f they don't help